# Compare non-exclusive/ overlapping populations

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

Let's take this non-sense sample data:

```
   contin1 categor2 smokers lazy
         1        2       1    1
         2        2       1    1
         3        1       1    1
         4        2       0    1
         5        2       1    1
         6        1       0    1
         7        3       1    0
         8        1       1    0
         9        1       0    0
        10        1       0    0
```

How can I compare smokers (smokers == 1) and lazy people (lazy == 1) with each other?

- For `contin1` (continuous Variable) I would normally use a ttest or utest.
- For `categor2` a Chisq-test.

When comparing lazy ppl with smokers the two groups have duplicated values. How do I deal with that? Whats the right test to see if they are "statistically different" or associated?

Comment: You can use a regression model with dependent variable contin1 and regressors smokers and lazy. Then compare the regression coefficients of the two regressors using a contrast test. I can't think of any other approach.

Answer (score 0):

Since These are categories you should straight go for Chi-Sq test, i don't understand what duplicate values you are talking about. If you can make the Contingency table from this data this would be like this.

The Values are as per your data.

[image]

Please explain what duplicate values you are talking about and whats your hypothesis.

**UPDATE:**
First this is a sample data and second this only a contingency table not the chisq result.

But one thing can be done if you take smoker to be a binary target variable  and lazy to be independent variable and run a logistic regression and check the p-value of independent variable and then you can calculate odds, and also derive some relationship if exist.

Comment: @Andre is looking for a way to compare lazy people and smokers. To test if 1. these two populations have the same mean value for a given continuous variable `contin1` and 2. If the populations have the same representation of a given categorical variable `categor2`. 

We're not looking to see if there is the same number of lazy people as there are smokers in the study.